# mvvmlight - System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have a .net 4.0 wpf application which can run in Win7, Win8 and Win10, but got .net runtime error in windows xp sp3 when I try to raise the first RelayCommand in my login viewmodel, here is the error message detail picture below.

Any suggestion how to reslove this issue ?

[Runtime error message detail picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saZsI.png)

Comment: What does the code look like for your relay command definitions?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - otherwise, it is very difficult to help you.